# Problems using OVER PARTITION BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I have some trouble using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ...).`

I have the following table

```
StartTime | EndTime | ContractStart
----------+---------+--------------
10:00     |  12:00  | 2015-03-02
11:00     |  22:00  | 2014-01-02
10:00     |  12:00  | 2015-03-02
10:00     |  12:00  | 2014-01-02
```

The person had a work contract starting at the `2014-01-02`. Something in that contract changed and he got a new one at the `2015-03-02`. Now I want to sum up the working time for the new contract. My code is:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(DATEDIFF(Minute, table.StartTime, table.EndTime))
FROM
    (SELECT 
         *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ContractStart 
                            ORDER BY ContractStart DESC) AS seqnum
     FROM table) table
WHERE 
    seqnum = 1
```

I actually thought that the code would divide the table into two partitions. one with the data for each contract. Now every partition gets a number. Since I set `ORDER BY ContractStart DESC` the latest contract is in the first partition which I choose in the `Where Clause` of the query. My result is always `0` and I do not know what is wrong with the code. Can anyone tell what is wrong with the code and why it is not producing the result I want.

Comment: Provide desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you did partition the data by `ContractStart`, sure. But then the row number doesn't actually tell you anything useful:

```
StartTime|EndTime|ContractStart|seqnum
10:00    |12:00  |2015-03-02   |1
11:00    |22:00  |2014-01-02   |1
10:00    |12:00  |2015-03-02   |2
10:00    |12:00  |2014-01-02   |2
```

You don't actually want a windowing function - all you need is a simple `group by`:

```
select
 top 1
 sum(datediff(Minute, StartTime, EndTime))
from [table]
group by [ContractStart]
order by [ContractStart] desc
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One question just for understanding. Wouldn't be the seqnum sequence 1,2,1,2 instead of 1,1,2,2?

Comment: @ruedi No. The thing is, you're partitioning the rownumber by the conract. That means that for each contract, there is a separate row numbering - as if you slapped together the queries filtered by one contract after another. You actually want the exact opposite - to assign a single number to all rows pertaining to the same contract.

Comment: @ruedi To make it more clear, you are assuming that the `row_number` is applied on the partitions - instead, the `row_number` is applied separately on the data in each partition, a separate sequence for each of the partitions.

Comment: Ah oook. I got it! Thanks for explaining that to me!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach (depending on your desired output).

```
SELECT ContractStart, SUM(DATEDIFF(Minute, StartTime, EndTime)) AS WorkingTime
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY ContractStart
```

Output:

```
ContractStart               WorkingTime
January, 02 2014 00:00:00   780
March, 02 2015 00:00:00     240
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7d539/4/0

I'm also going to assume this would be part of a larger query (including employee id's of some sort) which could be included in the selection and group by.

**Pseudo**

```
SELECT e.id, c.ContractStart, SUM(DATEDIFF(Minute, c.StartTime, c.EndTime)) AS WorkingTime
FROM contracts c
INNER JOIN employee e ON c.employeeid = e.id
GROUP BY e.id, c.ContractStart
```